# How can I do conditional actions in SQLX

Tags: go, sqlx

I have database store function:
`func (p *ProductsRep) FindAll(PageNumber int, PaginationSize int, Query string) []*postgresmodels.Product {`

Also I have SQL query look like this:
`SELECT * FROM table_name`.

Then I want to concat conditional action like `WHERE some_value=3` if some value (in this case Query) exists then I want to get `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_value=3`.
I tried to use `fmt.Sprintf` to concat, or `strings.Join`, or `bytes.Buffer.WriteString`. But everytime I getting this error:

I replace real value for understanding:
`pq: column "Some value" does not exist.`

How can I do "adaptive" queries, which depends on inputed function values.

Comment: sqlx is just a database access layer. It doesn't offer any logic capabilities. Your logic must live either in your Go code (unrelated to sqlx), or in your query (also unrelated to sqlx)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to query rows in the database by using parameters.

You need to make sure you don't pass this data in as RAW values, due to the potential risk of SQL injection. You can make queries by using store procedures

You can use the function `Query` to pass in your query with your parameters. In the example case this is `$1`. If you wanted to you could add `$2, $3...` etc depending on how many parameters you wanted to query

Here is two examples

Postgres
using "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4" driver

```
    ctx := context.Background()
    type Bar struct {
        ID        int64
        SomeValue string
    }

    rows, err := conn.Query(ctx, `SELECT * FROM main WHERE some_value=$1`, "foo")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERRO")
        panic(err) // handle error
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var items []Bar
    for rows.Next() {
        var someValue string
        var id int64
        if err := rows.Scan(&id, &someValue); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err) // handle error
        }
        item := Bar{
            ID:        id,
            SomeValue: someValue,
        }
        items = append(items, item)
    }
    fmt.Println(items)
```

MySQL Driver
https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow

```
    type Bar struct {
        ID        int64
        SomeValue string
    }

    rows, err := conn.Query(`SELECT * FROM main WHERE some_value=$1`, "foo")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERRO")
        panic(err) // handle error
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var items []Bar
    for rows.Next() {
        var someValue string
        var id int64
        if err := rows.Scan(&id, &someValue); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err) // handle error
        }
        item := Bar{
            ID:        id,
            SomeValue: someValue,
        }
        items = append(items, item)
    }
    fmt.Println(items)
```